# Decorate a read function that changes the way of opening a file

Tags: python, python-3.6, decorator, python-decorators, zip

I have the following function

```
def read_tower(path_to_file):

    with open(path_to_file,'r') as f:

        for text in f:

            text_line = text.strip().split(" ")
```

My idea is to use a decorator to change that function so I can read files from a zip folder like

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(Path(zip_filename)) as z:
    for filename in z.namelist():
        if re.search(r'.*\.mlm',filename):
            #with z.open(filename,mode="r") as f:
            data = read_tower(f)
```

So basically I want to decorate **read_tower** so I can use **z.open** instead of **open**.

I am very new to decorators yet. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think this should a decorator instead of a conditional statement?

Comment: Becasue a conditional statement needs another argument for the function and I need to write more code. I want to improve my decorator skills as well.

Comment: Does it need another argument? Would `if path_to_file.endswith('.zip'):` not be sufficient?  You would need to write more code either way, since you would need to write a decorator function. Edit: which would also likely include a conditional like that.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.....

Comment: With the decorator functionality I expect to change "open(filename,r)" function

Comment: `open = your_open_func`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this using decorator, you may inject the ContextManager of any file type into the reading, writing (or any other processing you need) logic, something like this:

```
def reader(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        with func(*args, **kwargs) as f:
            for text in f:
                text_line = text.strip().split(" ")
            ...      
    return wrap

@reader
def file_reader(*args, **kwargs):
    return open(*args, **kwargs)

@reader
def zipfile_reader(z, *args, **kwargs):
   return z.open(*args, **kwargs)

file_content = file_reader(<path>, <mode>)
zipfile_content = zipfile_reader(zipfile_obj, <filename>, <extra_args>)
```

But I recommend simply to extract the common logic from the `read_tower` into a separate  function:

```
def read_file_content(file):
    for text in f:
        text_line = text.strip().split(" ")
    ...
```

file usage:

```
with open('..path', mode) as f:
    read_file_content(f)
```

zipfile usage:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(Path(zip_filename)) as z:
    for filename in z.namelist():
        if re.search(r'.*\.mlm',filename):
            with z.open(filename,mode="r") as f:
                read_file_content(f)
```

**Note**: code here is just to give idea, it is not completely working code.

Comment: Thanks but I tried your code and file_content appears empty...

Comment: you are welcome, this because your function does not return anthing, just accumlate your result then return. @JPV

Comment: How would you do to decore two functions ?  Imagine, if you would like to decore the open(path,mode) function and as well the logic from read tower.